# Diagonal swipe on web view populated by html script buggy after zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a web view that display a table much larger than the screen. When I try to scroll it diagonally AFTER zooming - both in or out, it usually only scrolls in a single direction instead of diagonally. Is this behaviour due to web view's scrollview or could I have made mistake in my codes?

This is how I populate my web view:

```
    webViewContent.scrollView.bounces = false
    webViewContent.scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
    webViewContent.scrollView.delegate = self
    webViewContent.scalesPageToFit = true

    var htmlString = "<html><head>... ... a really long string that creates a table"
    webViewContent.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Please do tell me if the htmlString might affect, I did not include it because it is really long.

I also tried to synchronise the view with a header row called webViewTitle which I populate using similar codes but only one row. The synchronise codes are like:

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollView != webViewTitle.scrollView){
        var zoomPadding:CGFloat = 0.0
        if((currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale) < 1){
            zoomPadding = 0.5*(-acos(currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale)*180.0/CGFloat.pi)
        }else{
            zoomPadding = 0.5*acos(2-(currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale))*180.0/CGFloat.pi
        }
        webViewTitle.scrollView.zoom(to: CGRect(x: webViewContent.scrollView.contentOffset.x,
                                                y: (355*currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale) + zoomPadding,
                                                width: webViewTitle.scrollView.bounds.width/currentZoomScale/webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale,
                                                height: webViewTitle.scrollView.bounds.height/currentZoomScale/webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale),
                                     animated: false)
    }
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var zoomPadding:CGFloat = 0.0
    if((currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale) < 1){
        zoomPadding = 0.5*(-acos(currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale)*180.0/CGFloat.pi)
    }else{
        zoomPadding = 0.5*acos(2-(currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale))*180.0/CGFloat.pi
    }
    if(scrollView == webViewTitle.scrollView){
        webViewTitle.scrollView.contentOffset.y = (355*currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale) + zoomPadding
        webViewContent.scrollView.contentOffset.x = webViewTitle.scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }else{
        webViewTitle.scrollView.contentOffset.y = (355*currentZoomScale*webViewContent.scrollView.zoomScale) + zoomPadding
        webViewTitle.scrollView.contentOffset.x = webViewContent.scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }
}
```

Could any of these caused the diagonal scrolling to become buggy?

Answer (score -1):

> Could any of these caused the diagonal scrolling to become buggy?

Yes

From the provided code, you are implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for the `UIWebView`, but in both shown implementations, you are not calling `super`. This means that the `scrollView` is not going to have it's standard behavior, and instead strictly use your code for it's `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewDidZoom` behavior.

While this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577114/large-page-in-uiwebview-not-always-scrolling-diagonally) doesn't necessarily provide a lot of clarity on exactly what is going on, I believe it to be the same issue you're facing.

In summary: At a minimum, call `super` for each delegate implementation of the `UIScrollViewDelegate`, or if you don't need any custom scroll behavior then remove the `delegate` altogether.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about calling `super`? I did not subclass `UIWebView` nor `UIScrollView` in this implementation. This Piece of code is in my View Controller subclass, by calling `super` here I am calling `UIViewController` which is not a `UIScrollViewdelegate`. By calling the `superView` of the `scrollView`, I am calling the `contentView` of my View Controller, which is just a `UIView`